# simple iir filter implementation in C++

Tags: filters, infinite-impulse-response, c

I am programming the simplest way of implementing and IIR filter. However, I am struggling with the use of buffers. Do any of you have any simple implementation of an IIR filter implementing manually the convolution? I would like to have something simple, implemented on a function or something like that on C/C++.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you google IIR filter C++ source code? There are dozens of online sources out there.

Comment: I did but most of them are outdated or not working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, you could use a couple of easiest and more optimized solutions, unless you need only that filter and you want to avoid third party or extra library/files:

- SigPack: http://sigpack.sourceforge.net/index.html
- Kfr: https://www.kfr.dev/

Cheers.

Comment: Cool! I will have a look into it!